# Git commit -m does not accept spaces in the message

Tags: git, shell, double-quotes

I am relatively new to Linux so this is probably an easy one but when I use quotes (single or double) around my git commit messages the words are taken as filenames. How do I use -m with spaces in the message - I do not want to use vi.

```
user@linux:~/Documents/tmp$ git status

On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   afile

user@linux:~/Documents/tmp$ git commit -m ¨this message has spaces and fails¨ 

error: pathspec 'message' did not match any file(s) known to git.

error: pathspec 'has' did not match any file(s) known to git.

error: pathspec 'spaces' did not match any file(s) known to git.

error: pathspec 'and' did not match any file(s) known to git.

error: pathspec 'fails¨' did not match any file(s) known to git.

user@linux:~/Documents/tmp$ git commit -m ¨nospacesisokay¨

[master (root-commit) 37afcd6] ¨nospacesisokay¨

1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

create mode 100644 afile
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use regular quotes (double quotes `"`, or quotes `'`), fellow :) `¨` is too exotic for *bash* so it splits down your message into tokens by whitespaces and pass these tokens separately to `git`.

In unix-like systems, unlike MS Windows `cmd.exe`, (well, MinGW and Cygwin are unix-like too :) ) splitting command line into tokens is peformed by a shell, be it a `sh`- or `csh`-compatible shell (bash, zsh, ash, sash, ksh, tcsh and so on and so forth). A program receives a ready to use array of arguments. So if a user wants to pass a line with spaces, escape-sequences and so on, she should quote or escape that line properly.

Comment: That doesn't seem to affect it. I use double quotes tons.

Comment: His double quotes actually aren't regular "english quotes".

Comment: I am pressing the normal double quotes key. Must be my keyboard settings! This page indicates that there is no way to fix it other than to reinstall ubuntu :-(. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1346574. Seems I selected us-intl (because I have no idea what I am doing or what that means) and that creates this ridiculous issue where the double quote is a stupid unicode character which the terminal does not understand. Oh, joy.

Comment: Oh, no, don't reinstall, better investigate and fix! It's due to locale settings and a too clever text editor. For example LibreOffice provides four or even more quoting styles depending on the paragraph language and other settings, like this: “English text”  «Русский текст (Russian Text)»

Comment: IMHO, Us-Intl isn't well suited for a programmer due to quoting issues. I'm using "US-International AltGr dead keys" to seamlessly edit English and Spanish texts as well as regular source code.

Comment: maybe you can do `git commit -m this\ message\ has\ spaces\ and\ fails`

Comment: @user859400 The question has been answered with a correct answer. Your problem is the quotes. You should accept the answer and ask how to change your keyboard layout in a ubuntu forum. Basically go to system settings, keyboard, add a second layout (US) and use a key combination to change layout (e.g. alt-shift).

Comment: @user3159253 I agree with US-Int not being the best for programmers, simple US is the best, however I use US-Int and I can tell you it works for anybody that knows how to enable more than one layout and change them. I don't see why you have to stick with a single layout for all tasks.

Comment: Well, actually I have three "ordinary" input languages, English, Spanish and Russian (and use Ukrainian from time to time :) ). Obviously Cyrillic languages demand their own layout(s). But Spanish alphabet has too few differences from English and these diacritic symbols are relatively rare. That's why I prefer to enter them using dead key modifier (caps lock in my setups)

Comment: @user859400  please be patient! Of course I will accept this answer, but I have only just got back to my computer. As for öff-topic"- I don see how it is off-topic. I was having a problem with git so I asked a question about it. SO has become too negative recently, users get chastised for the tiniest things.

Comment: @user859400 looking at your "öff-topic" (My German friends smile :) ) I'm assuming that you're still w/ US-Intl layout which uses " as a prefix for diacritics like Ä, Ë and Ï :) I sincerely suggest you to change the layout because I know how annoying it is :) If you don't need to enter texts in West-European languages then choose US, otherwise choose one of those layouts w/ dead letters (diacritics are entered as AltGr+BaseLetter by default) or create a separate layout as DavidG suggests.

Comment: For reference executing "setxkbmap -layout us" in a terminal fixed the issue. I am not sure if it has to be re-entered every time you reboot/login though.

Comment: it has to be re-entered every time. In Ubuntu it's better to configure layout from the configuration panel as [shown here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByR3uTWe1yI). Also it's better to move onto http://AskUbuntu.com